# How to return a Forward_Iterator of a Hashed_Set in Ada?

Tags: iterator, containers, ada

I want to return a Forward_Iterator over the elements of an hashed_set in Ada, like in the code below:

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Hashed_Sets;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Hash;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure debug is
   package my_set is new Ada.Containers.Hashed_Sets
     (Element_Type        => Unbounded_String, 
      Hash                => Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Hash, 
      Equivalent_Elements => "=");

   function get_Iterator
     (some_set : my_set.set)
      return my_set.Set_Iterator_Interfaces.Forward_Iterator'Class is                 --' Highlight fix
   begin
      return some_set.Iterate;
   end;

   set_1 : my_set.set;

begin
   set_1.insert(To_Unbounded_String("element"));
   for E in get_Iterator (some_set => set_1) loop
      put_line ("i iterate!");
   end loop;

end debug;
```

The problem is that the code raises a program error 
"raised PROGRAM_ERROR : debug.adb:6 finalize/adjust raised exception" which i do not understand ... (im using GNAT Ada GPL 2014 under Ubuntu 14.04)

Is there a way to repair the code? Or is there another possibility to return an iterator over a hashed_set? An application for this is e.g. the case when the hashed_set is part of an private record and it should only be possible to iterate the elements from outside, but not to change the set itself.

Thanks in advance!

PS: This is my first question here, so if you have any tips for improving the question, please tell me :)

Comment: Snippets don’t work for Ada; as far as I know they only work for JavaScript! I get the same error with GCC 5.0.0 but not GCC 4.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found a bug in GNAT.  Please submit your example to the GCC bug database.

But why do you want an explicit iterator object?  Usually you just loop over the container leaving the compiler to mess with handling the iterator object.

Comment: sounds like he's creating a wrapper (private record) around a container, but still wants the user to iterate the actual container

Comment: For what it's worth, the code seems to work as expected with Gnat Pro 7.1.x

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post my solution to this problem.
I had the possiblity to check the problem with Gnat Pro 7.2.x and I does not appear anymore. But If you do I similar approach using a Hashed_Map instead of a Hashed_Set, it was still there.

Since I also got access to the GNATtracker, I postet my problem there and was told that this is indead a compiler bug. The compiler is generating an incorrect accessibility check at the Get_Iterator function.

Hence, the workaround that was suggested, was to just suppress the corresponding check for the function:

```ada
   function get_Iterator
     (some_set : my_set.set)
      return my_set.Set_Iterator_Interfaces.Forward_Iterator'Class is                 --' Highlight fix
      pragma Suppress (Accessibility_Check); -- workaround to suppress buggy check
   begin
      return some_set.Iterate;
   end;
```

This workaround works for me with Gnat Pro 7.2.x and Gnat GPL 2014 for both, Hashed_Sets and Hashed_Maps.